# Relationship between Bias/Variance and Covariates in Ridge/Lasso Regression

Tags: regression, lasso, bias, ridge-regression, bias-variance-tradeoff

Suppose I add irrelevant (i.e. *no explanatory power*) regressors to a ridge/lasso regression. Does this impact the model bias/variance?

In the case of OLS, the model bias remains unchanged, while the variance increases if the regressors are not correlated with each other within the sample, as far as I am concerned.

Comment: Do you mean uncorrelated at the sample level (observed/calculated) or at the population level (I observed/assumed)?

Comment: Do you refer to the attribute "irrelevant"?

Comment: I mean what you say about the predictors being correlated with one another.

Comment: I have not made any assumption regarding that in my question. I am aware that it might depend on wether they are or are not, thats why I have not made an assumption.

Comment: Regarding the OLS case I was mentioning, I was referring to the sample.

Comment: Please incorporate the clarifications in coments as an edit to the post. Not everybody reads comments!

Comment: Alright, I did so.